# Cocos2d-x Director replaceScene with Transition

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

i m using cocos2d-x version 3.2 and can't use Transition with animation between two scene.

ndk-stack show this error :

```
 cocos2d::Scheduler::unscheduleAllForTarget(void*)+55
```

caused in this Class CCScheduler.cpp (Line 534)

```
 HASH_FIND_PTR(_hashForTimers, &target, element);
```

is this a know issue ? or maybe i m doing some thing wrong in my code ?

thanks

---

```
class FirstScene : public Scene {    
....
scene()...
init(){
auto overlay = NodeInFirstScene::create();
this->addChild(overlay);
}
}
```

Overlay

```
Class NodeInFirstScene : public Node {
void NodeInScene1::ButtonPressed() {
Director::sharedDirector()->replace(TransitionFade::create(1.2,SecondScene::scene());
}
}
```

SecondScene

```
Class SecondScene : public Scene {
//
scene()....
init()...
}
```

if i use

```
 Director::sharedDirector()->pushScene it work fine !!
```

Comment: post your code and the exact eror message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve it,

First : Add method in header :

```
virtual void release();
virtual void onExit(); //
```

Second : Release any objects inside my custom class.

```
CC_SAFE_RELEASE(mObject);
unscheduleAllSelectors();
...
```

Voila,